# Remove all old files without removing software on Windows XP

Tags: file-management

so I recently acquired my old build from my dad, and it is cluttered with a ton of old files that I don't need/want.  Is there a way that I can easily get rid of all the old things without deleting the installed applications and things?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the previous user kept files inside their user directory (including the desktop), you could always make a new (administrative) user account and delete the old one. This should get rid of any TEMP files they had as well, as those live in the user's Local Settings folder in XP.